# '\n' not detected by VTTCue for video subtitles in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to play a video with subtitles. I'm extracting duration and the subtitles string from a `subtitles.txt` file. The subtitles are extracted and player properly but the `next line = '\n'` is not being detected by 'code'. So please help me.

The Output I want:

```
Golden dreams
and great heartache
```

The Output I get:

```
Golden dreams\nand great heartache
```

---

My `subtitles.txt` File:

```
211 --> 223
"Golden dreams\nand great heartache"
```

My Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <video video-player src="video.mp4"></video>
  <script>
    var video_player = document.querySelectorAll('[video-player]')[0];
    
    track_english = video_player.addTextTrack("captions", undefined, "en");
    track_english.mode = "showing";
    subtitles_xhr(function(buffer)
    {
      var file = buffer;
      file = file.split('\n');
      for (var x = 0; x < file.length; x+=2)
      {
        track_english.addCue(new VTTCue(file[x].split(" --> ")[0], file[x].split(" --> ")[1], file[x+1]));
      }
    });
    
    function subtitles_xhr (cb)
    {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
      xhr.open('GET', "subtitles.txt");
      xhr.onload = function ()
      {
        cb(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.send();  
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `\n` characters displayed when your read your text file are actually `\\n` characters.

These characters won't get identified by the VTTCue parser as being new lines, so you need to replace these characters in the third argument of the *VTTCue* constructor to actual new lines, `\n`.

```js
// make the file available in StackSnippet
const txt_uri = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([String.raw`1 --> 13
"Golden dreams\nand great heartache"`], {type: 'text/plain'}));

var video_player = document.querySelectorAll('[video-player]')[0];

track_english = video_player.addTextTrack("captions", undefined, "en");
track_english.mode = "showing";
subtitles_xhr(function(buffer) {
  var file = buffer;
  file = file.split('\n');
  for (var x = 0; x < file.length; x += 2) {
    let startTime = file[x].split(" --> ")[0],
      endTime = file[x].split(" --> ")[1],
      content = file[x + 1]
       .replace(/\\n/g, '\n'); // here replace all occurrences of '\\n' with '\n'
    track_english.addCue(
      new VTTCue(startTime, endTime, content)
    );
  }
});

function subtitles_xhr(cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', txt_uri);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    cb(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```css
video{max-height:100vh}
```

```html
<video video-player src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm" autoplay controls></video>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thanks a lot for your answer. It works perfectly